# Jmeter Testrun is getting end although duration time is given

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to run a JMeter test where I want to run a test having 1 user, the ramp-up period is 1 second, the loop will be one and the duration is 120 seconds, I want to run my test having one loop for 2 mins or as required

Comment: What you want it to run?

Comment: I have recorded an e-com site and want to run it using one user, ramp up is 1 sec, the loop is one, and duration want to give 2 mins

Answer (score 0):

If `the loop will be one` then your test will end as soon as JMeter will finish executing the last [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or when 120 seconds pass, whatever comes the first.

If you want to run the Samplers for 2 minutes - set the `Loop Count` to `-1` or tick `Infinite` box:

[image]

If you're having the hard time trying to configure JMeter's workload using normal Thread Group you can take a look at i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which provides way more flexible way to define ramp-up, time to hold the load, ramp-down, spikes, etc. Ultimate Thread Group can be installed as a part of **Custom Thread Groups** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

Comment: In the case of loop 1 and duration of 120 seconds, the test is getting finished in a few seconds and does not run for 120seconds I am trying for that one loop last for 120 seconds, and I am trying for the ultimate thread group now as per your suggestion.